# How do I find the result of a previous background run of DB05?

Tags: sap-basis

In transaction `DB05` you can check the selectivity of different fields of a table. For huge tables you should start it in the background, to avoid timeouts.

If I do this however, how can I find the result two hours later, when the job finished?

---

If this question belongs to a sister site, please move it there.

Comment: Background jobs: SM37 - or do I miss something?

Comment: @JozsefSzikszai, In SM37 I can see _if_ it finished, but not the selectivity of the fields

Comment: Can't you navigate to the spool in SM37? I run it online in DB05 and in the background and I can't see any difference between the two lists. There is also no added functionality (double click on lines, icons, etc,) in the online list as well (at least by me)

Comment: @JozsefSzikszai turn this into an answer, and I will accept it, others might find it useful too. Also, _thanks_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background jobs: SM37
If you display the finished job, select it and click "Spool" (Pushbutton, above, about in the middle). Now you get to the spool, select it again and click the "Glasses" Icon. Yous should see the same list, like you would have run the report online.